# CMAKE ExternalProject_Add add unwanted double quote

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake

I have a simple CMake project that uses ExternalProject_Add to configure and compile ffmpeg. The CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(FFMpeg)

include(ExternalProject)

set(PRIVATE_LIBRARY_PATH "home/user/local/lib")
set(PRIVATE_PKG_CONFIG "home/user/local/pkgconfig")

set(FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_COMMAND echo)
if(NOT (EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FFMpeg/config.h))
    set(FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure)
    set(FFMPEG_DEBUG_CONFIGURE_ARGS "--enable-x86asm --disable-doc --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-avx512 --disable-optimizations --extra-cflags=-g3 --extra-cflags=-fno-omit-frame-pointer --enable-debug=3 --extra-cflags=-fno-inline --disable-stripping")
endif()

ExternalProject_Add(ffmpeg
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PRIVATE_LIBRARY_PATH} PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PRIVATE_PKG_CONFIG}/usr/lib/pkgconfig && ${FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_COMMAND} ${FFMPEG_DEBUG_CONFIGURE_XMA_ARGS}
        BUILD_COMMAND export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PRIVATE_LIBRARY_PATH} PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PRIVATE_PKG_CONFIG}/usr/lib/pkgconfig && make V=1
        INSTALL_COMMAND make install
        INSTALL_DIR ""
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        BUILD_ALWAYS 1)
```

But when the CONFIGURE_COMMAND of the ExternalProject_Add is being executed the command add double quotes between the expanded string FFMPEG_DEBUG_CONFIGURE_ARGS and thus the ffmpeg configure script dismiss the arguments:

```
./configure "--enable-x86asm --disable-doc --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-avx512 --disable-optimizations --extra-cflags=-g3 --extra-cflags=-fno-omit-frame-pointer --enable-debug=3 --extra-cflags=-fno-inline --disable-stripping"
```

How can I change the CONFIGURE_COMMAND command line to have the double quote removed to allow the FFMpeg configure script to properly recognize the argument?

Comment: Well, with quotes you make sure that you've got a "list" of 1 element containing all the command line parameters. Since spaces in a parameter would lead to the command line interpreting this as multiple parameters, CMake needs to insert quotes. Removing the quotes you've got a list with 13 elements containing one of the parameters each. (You can clearly see this by printing the list elements in a loop: `foreach(_TEMP IN LISTS FFMPEG_DEBUG_CONFIGURE_ARGS) message(STATUS "item: ${_TEMP}") endforeach()`)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the quote from the CMake set(...) fixed the issue. I didn't quite understand that you don't need to put the value of a set in a double quote. Thus the set should be:

```
    set(FFMPEG_DEBUG_CONFIGURE_ARGS --enable-x86asm --disable-doc --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-avx512 --disable-optimizations --extra-cflags=-g3 --extra-cflags=-fno-omit-frame-pointer --enable-debug=3 --extra-cflags=-fno-inline --disable-stripping)
```